# Including signature images kills scrlttr2

Tags: scrlttr2

I'm really weirded out. The following letter compiles nicely:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[a4paper, textwidth=490pt, textheight = 690pt]{geometry}
\setkomavar{signature}{John Doe}
\begin{document} 
\begin{letter}{Dr X \\ Evil Corp}
\setkomavar{subject}{Application}
\opening{Dear Dr X,}
blabla
\closing{Kind regards,}
\end{letter} 
\end{document}
```

---

But when I include an (existing) signature image by replacing

```
\setkomavar{signature}{John Doe}
```

with

```
\setkomavar{signature}{\includegraphics{sig} \\\\ John Doe},
```

my compiler refuses to create a pdf, saying

```
Undefined control sequence \closing{Kind regards,}
```

I don't know what to do.

Comment: Welcome, has `\\\\` ever worked for you?

Comment: With the expected error of the four backslashes resolved (and loading `graphicx`), everything compiles fine.

Comment: I actually artificially included two backslashes as the stackexchange parser showed only one instead two (I didn't want to confuse anyone, but it seemed to have the exact opposite effect ;))

Comment: Torbjorn's answer was on point and solved the issue.

Comment: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Ah, thanks. I didn't know that highlighting-then-clicking hack, I was too lazy to paste every single line after inserting 4 blanks manually.

Comment: I use <ctrl+k> to highlight. Another thing, package `ngerman` is a bit obsolete. Better use `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is actually

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\scr@signature@var ->\includegraphics 
                                      {sig}John Doe
l.12 \closing{Kind regards,}
```

When you get a `Undefined control sequence` error, the macro (control sequence) it complains about is the last one on the first line, in this case `\includegraphics`.

`\includegraphics` is defined by the `graphicx` package, which should always be added if you're adding images. Hence, adding

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

will solve it.

Comment: Oh wow. I haven't even seen this error, it instantly thought that the OP forgot to put it in the example :-)

Comment: I read the error message, but I was thoroughly confused because in TeXstudio, the abbreviated error message just shows what I posted above (and doesn't include the  line  ! Undefined control sequence.
\scr@signature@var ->\includegraphics 
                                      {sig}John Doe)

Comment: @FasEtNefas I see. That can be a problem sometimes, editors parsing the log file wrongly.

Comment: At least this teaches me to read the actual log file, not just the TeXstudio's message board. Thanks!